# Why was my question downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746069/sorting-an-arraylist-of-objects-at-runtime). It was downvoted as users thought I had not done enough work on it. I did make the edits after getting so many downvotes.

But the thing is, I found another related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432774/how-do-i-make-2-comparable-methods-in-only-one-class) and this question was upvoted 8 times. I don't understand how this question reflects effort on the part of poster and mine doesn't.

PS: I am not complaining about getting downvoted. I am only asking about the problems with my question as compared to the latter question so that I might keep these points in mind before posting a question next time.

Comment: Keep in mind that the post you link to is from 2010. It has received trickle upvotes over time and might no longer accurately reflect what is appropriate for the site anyway.

Comment: Any question that ends with "I need to do X. Any suggestions will be helpful" will be downvoted and closed very quickly.  We are not here to do your work for you.  Limit your questions to specific technical issues you have.  Your edits have not made the question useful, it is still asking for people to do the work for you.

Comment: @JK.Thanks for being so rude, but I was not asking for complete solutions. I was only asking for the approach. As an example, the first two comments on my question were helpful. I understand that anybody is not here to do work for anybody.

Comment: @Pankaj He wasn't being rude, he was politely informing you of how the site works, and what you did wrong (correctly I might add), in response to your request for feedback on your question.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in my posts. Mostly you come to this type of forus in order to get some ideas when yours have already runned out, am i right? So, i know that perhaps not everyone will have the right answer, that is why at the end i always write: Any help is welcome!.                                                                                            But at the end i still no get it why people has downvoted my questions, there should be a place to specify the reason why was downvoted that question so you could see if he/she is right.

Answer (score 22):

In the future, consider showing original code that you've written. Do consider asking a question after you get stuck - not before you start. I realize that you don't want to waste time, however the "best" solution is rather subjective.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to what @bart mentioned in the comments, the reason that question received upvotes is because the site was a lot different back in 2010. Questions asking for tools and libraries and the like were on topic back then, and there wasn't a review system like we have today. Questions that didn't include relevant code or an attempt by the user to do some research on their own, etc were all fine back then.

As the site grew, it became obvious to weed out these broad and poor questions. I second what Andy Jones said in his answer here. People do not like answering questions where the OP hasn't even tried what they are asking about. Like run at least one test yourself, see what errors, if any, you're getting, and if you get stuck, then ask a question including the relevant code, and a  short as possible description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the initial state of your question is that you were asking a too broad question.

If you had explained more specifically what you needed you would be less likely to get downvotes.

You are not obligated to show your code, you don't have to prove your effort (some people might disagree), you just have to ask a specific and clear question.