# How can we make sure that new posters know that they should remain available over the next 30-60 mins after posting?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

I notice regularly that folks who are new to Stack Overflow often post their question and then are not on the site for some significant time (e.g. hours).  If their question is not entirely clear (which they often are not for people new to the site) and the question is targeted at a high traffic tag like "javascript" or "c#" where the pace/volume just moves faster, then a bunch of not so great things happen:

1. As the new question comes to everyone's attention, lots of people read it, try to figure it out, don't quite understand it and some people ask clarifying questions in the comments.
2. More people read the question, see the request for clarification and just move on - basically wasting their time and resources that could have been applied more usefully on the site.
3. Some people may venture a guess as to what the OP meant and post an answer based on that guess.  You may even get multiple answers based on different guesses as to what they wanted.  Unfortunately for all, these guesses are generally a waste of time for all.  One guess might happen to be mostly what the OP intended, but all the rest are simply a waste of time that could have been much more productively spent actually helping someone.
4. After some period of time with no response from the OP, often as short as 10-15 minutes, but sometimes longer, the question will start to receive down votes or close votes.  Now with the superpowers that some people have, it can only take one close vote to close the question or put it on hold.
5. Then, some time later (often many hours later), the OP returns and finds their question has been closed and people have been frustrated with them for writing a cryptic question and being non-responsive.  Most newbies who get their question closed just go away.  Even though there's a procedure that could provide clarification and get the question opened again, I don't think I've ever seen that happen for a new poster.  If nothing else, they're probably intimidated because it appears they've done something wrong (actually, they have).

The common thread in all of this is the new poster often disappears for some significant period of time after they post and they are not around to answer clarifying questions.  What we want people posting questions to know is this:

1. A huge percentage of the traffic that will see their question is going to happen in the first 30-60 minutes.  This is probably particularly true for questions in high traffic tags such as "javascript".  There's just so many questions that most people browsing the site look at recent questions, not old questions.
2. So, their best chance to get a good answer is in that first 30-60 minutes.  When they post the question, they need to make absolutely sure that the question is clear for everyone who sees it in that first 30-60 minutes.
3. Besides posting a crystal clear question in the first place, the best way to make sure the question is clear is to hang around and check for comments at the 10, 20 and 30 minute mark after posting.  If you do that, you will have an immediate opportunity to fix up your question if it is proving to not be clear exactly what you're asking.
4. In addition, if people are posting answers, you can comment on those answers in case the answers aren't quite hitting the mark of answering what you meant by your question.  Once you have an answer, that person is engaged with your question and you have a short window to engage back with them in case their answer isn't quite what you wanted.  If you aren't around when they post their question to see it shortly after they provide and you come back a long time later, you have a much lower chance of maintaining that engagement with them if you need or want more than they've written or they were a little off base with what you meant to ask.

It was pointed out to me by someone else I was discussing this issue with that this behavior of post, go away, then come back some long time later is perhaps what people are used to with internet forums or mailing lists.  Post a question on a mailing list, go to sleep, wake up in the morning and see who responded.  Stack Overflow doesn't really work that way (thank goodness).  It's much more interactive and treating it like a mailing list question will probably just result in a closed question unless you were perfectly clear in your first attempt.

---

So, this is all a long setup for the issue/feature request which is how can we make sure that new posters know that it is in their own best interests if they hang around for at least 30 minutes after they post to check for comments and answers to make sure that people understand their question and are able to provide answers or that the answers being provided are aimed in the right direction?

FYI, you can see a mini-discussion of this issue in the comments for this post: [Promises vs Reactive vs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296168/promises-vs-reactive-vs#comment39436968_25296168) which is where it was suggested I post here.  On that particular question, I was able to guess (correctly) what I thought the OP meant, but others did not understand the question so it was put on hold before the OP returned some number of hours later.  And the OP in that questions confirms that they were treating it like a mailing list posting.

Comment: This is, in fact, covered in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, where it says: *"After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!"*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That's good that it's written down, but how do we make sure that a lot more new posters know that?

Comment: This is really more of an issue on the high profile tags like c++, java, c# where turnover is huge. Niche tags don't have this problem. Of course, most new questions are in the high profile tags.

Comment: How about one of those annoying `onbeforeunload` popups reading something like, "Please return to this page 30 minutes from now to check for answers or comments."

Comment: Well, it's not uncommon for a developer to spend all day trying to dig out some bug and then, having failed, post on SO. Since SO is globally-accessible, it doesn't make sense to wait since the contributor who has the answer may be asleep, working or otherwise engaged.

Comment: @MartinJames Maybe the person with the answer is asleep but there's a much bigger set of people who can help the asker improve his question by asking for additional info.

Comment: The "superpowers" only allow the question to be closed *as a duplicate* with one vote.  And I don't see the harm in that if the person is closing as a duplicate responsibly.

Comment: Can't see a problem here, post the question and leave it for tomorrow is absolutely fine for me. If OP's question get closed because of it's not clear and not on site to improve it then OP needs to ask a better question next time..

Comment: Can we perhaps have some kind of banner on the top of the just asked question which includes that *after you post* wording and only show it for people with little experience?

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to expect a poster to hover over a question after posting it, nor discourage them from asking a question unless they can commit a certain time frame to babysitting it. You have no idea what their schedule is like, and it's unlikely to match yours. This isn't official, paid, real-time support.

Comment: @Superstringcheese - I disagree.  On the busy tags, it's simply a waste of everyone's time to post a question (that turns out to be unclear) and not hang around.  Lots of people in the SO community spend time trying to understand it, they ask clarifying questions and you're not around to fix your question.  Then, the community votes to close your question because it's "Unclear What You're Asking".  So, out of respect for the community and your own selfish best interests in getting a good answer, you should at least check back within 30-60 minutes to make sure your question was understood.

Comment: @Superstringcheese - Further, it seems like behaviors that end up wasting a lot of people's time on SO should be worked on to make that issue happen less often.  That makes SO a better and more efficient place to be - which is a win for all.

Comment: @Bolu - And it doesn't bother you that the SO community wastes a lot of time on these unclear questions where the OP disappeared for a long time.  It does bother me.  I could be helping more deserving people rather than wasting my time on someone who doesn't have the decency to make sure their question was understood clearly.  I think SO would be a better and more productive place if this happened less often, therefore I think it's worth trying to figure out how to make it happen less often.

Comment: @jfriend00, how could that waste a lot of time? I don't know you, but I certainly won't stare at the screen and press F5 until OP response for my comment. Instead I'll just post my comment and move on, whenever I noticed a flag in my inbox (instantly or after a few days), that's the time I will revisit the question (if I feel it's necessary). Again, I think you are targeting the wrong problem.

Comment: If they don't care, why would I?

Comment: If I need help with something, I will post a question and keep my eyes here. This doesn't mean I wouldn't carry on with other tasks. I just won't leave the question alone because I need an answer.

Comment: And when I'm here to help people, I expect the same from them. If you just post a, somehow, incomplete question and just leave it alone, I'll assume it's not that important to you. So, why would I care about it? I just move on to other questions from people that really need help.

Comment: I don't think SO should bother about creating mechanisms to improve people's good sense.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Poor questions with unresponsive posters clutter up SO and make it a less productive place to be.  It costs time and energy of people who spend a lot of time helping people (I count myself in that category with more than 5k answers).  I'm frankly baffled that people would rather we let clueless posters just go right on being clueless rather than at least make an effort to educate them and help create higher quality posts.  SO doesn't work like a mailing list (thank goodness) and the faster newbies understand that, the better this place will be.

Comment: As the opposite of places using instant messaging (like irc), does not StackExchange precisely allow users to have discussions spread over hours/days and answers remembered for years ?

Comment: I remember when I first started using the site.... I asked a question, navigated away, and then could not find it again. There's nothing special about me, and many folks have probably experienced the same. A message box or proactive information on "how to locate your question" probably would have been helpful for those first couple posts.

Comment: (WARNING TO THE HUMOR IMPAIRED! Reductio ad absurdum follows!) The way to handle this is simple: 1) recruit a League Of Jack-Booted StackOverflow Thugs across the globe, followed by 2) when a new user logs in immediately locate the user, send an SOThug to wherever he/she/it is and have said SOThug stand over said new user, not allowing him/her/it to leave for two hours following the user's first post so that they will be available to address any issues surrounding the post. **THAT** should take care of problems with new posters! **BU-WA-HA-HA-HA-HA-HA-HA!!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 42):

This is attempting to solve the wrong problem. The problem is that people post questions with insufficient details and that forces other people to interact with them in the comments.

Yes, I know exactly what you're talking about. I get caught in this trap all the time. I'm always leaving comments that ask clarification questions. Sometimes I will revisit the question later to see if they're answered, but that's far from guaranteed. I only have so much browser tab real estate available on my screen. And with the way modern browsers leak memory, the number I can have open is getting smaller and smaller.

But rather than finding a way to promote this type of interaction, how about we figure out a way to get people to *ask good questions*?

And if they don't care to ask good questions, well, why should we invest so much time and energy into something they aren't willing to do the same for?

We don't *want* questions where there has to be a dialogue in the comments in order to figure out what they're asking. These are low-quality questions, not well-suited for the Stack Exchange format. Sure, occasionally it happens that you forget something or that there is something you omitted because you didn't think was possibly relevant. That's why we *have* comments that provide the opportunity to do this. But the spirit of your proposal is to place emphasis on this feature, to encourage its use more widely. And I think that misses the point.

Comment: It's hard for a newbie to do everything right from the first attempt. Even if he's read all the rules and really tries to provide all the details it may so happen that he's a real newbie in software development or in a specific technology. So a more experienced user could have helped him if the OP just provided *that specific detail* which the OP considered unimportant and omitted. With newbies it often has to be iterational and that requires interaction.

Comment: Of course we'd like to have better questions to start with.  When you know how to solve that problem so that no questions ever need further clarification, then I guess we wouldn't need to work on this aspect of things.  But, until then, there are lots and lots of questions that do need clarification and when the OP isn't around for hours or days afterwards, SO doesn't really work very well for those questions.  It's ineffective for the OP and wastes the time of people who are on SO to help others.  It seems worthwhile trying to improve the process when the question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: *"SO doesn't really work very well for those questions."* Correct.

Comment: Agree with sharptooth, if newbies can't be bothered to read instructions, or they fail to understand, the best we can do is keep encouraging them and correcting them. It's iterative...... *insert quotes here about "iterative learning", "practice makes perfect"

Comment: @gitsitgo - Do you not believe there are any opportunities to prevent mistakes before they happen?  Yes, the system is iterative.  Make a mistake with an unclear question, waste a bunch of people's time in the SO community, get downvoted or closed.  See if you learn from that.  I'd personally rather invest in avoiding at least some of these mistakes in the first place which both gives first time posters a better experience AND makes the SO community more productive (more time to help more people).

Comment: @sharptooth No, it is not difficult for newbies to follow the rules. It is difficult for lazy or rude newcomers to ask good questions. Good riddance to them. It is difficult for newcomers who do not understand even the basics of programming to write good questions. But this is not meant to be a site for them; this is for professionals and enthusiasts.

Comment: Getting good at anything takes practice and repetition. Even if you read all of the guidelines and best practices, it is still someone's first question on a site they have never asked a question before. Practice makes perfect. In school I read all of the literature, paid attention in lectures, etc., but my first programs were still not so great. They didn't get better until I wrote a whole lot more of them, and until my peers/professors gave me feedback on what I did wrong/what I could do better.

Comment: @jww I don't think that's the solution. I've answered nearly as many *good* questions from conscientious new users as I have utter crap from people who just don't care. Not only do I think it's unfair to blacklist people just because they're new, I also don't think it will solve the problem. There are plenty of people who have managed to accumulate reputation and accept answers but still post terrible questions that you and I want to stay miles away from. The only solution, of course, is downvoting those questions. It isn't hard to avoid them, you can tell at a glance which questions are good.

Comment: @sharptooth I went back and looked at my first few questions here.  None of them needed editing for clarification.  I don't think I'm exceptional.  It's not difficult to ask good questions, but it does take some time, hence my belief that people who ask bad questions are often being lazy (and not Larry Wall's good kind of lazy).

Comment: @WayneConrad Lazy as in "don't do too much" is normal, that's the point where other users should explain what else is needed.

Comment: _"And with the way modern browsers leak memory, the number I can have open is getting smaller and smaller."_ Yeah :(

Answer (score 20):

Posts are not a live conversation where you should expect an immediate, prompt response from the other party. Sometimes you get good answers or comments right away, but sometimes you get these only days after asking. I can kinda remember cases where it had been weeks before someone with the same problem as I found one of my questions and asked for clarification.

That said, IMO getting anxious because your comments are not being answered quickly here is worse than getting anxious because someone isn't answering you in some IM. SO is supposed to be a site for professionals and enthusiasts to help each other regarding programming, not a place to socialize.

Last but not least, rushing things may give strength to a reputation hunting culture. Some people want details on a question **now** because they want to **post fast and get points** (I'm not saying this is your case). If you really care for correctness, you should wait. If the OP is really interested in getting their problem  solved, they will come back and provide more details. If not, then to the limbo with their *unclear-what-you-are-asking* questions.

**Edit:** There's one aspect that I hadn't taken into account originally in my answer. As jfriend00 says:

> None of that helps you much when your question is closed 30 minutes after you asked because it wasn't clear what was being asked and you weren't around to answer the comments asking for clarification.

In that case the OP may edit their question for clarification and get the question reopened. There is a whole process for that in place already. You say that this doesn't happen often because new users get intimidated. I can kinda agree and I think that making it **more clear that their question may, and probably will be reopened if they just take the time to edit it for clarity** may be a good path to follow. I think this has been discussed throughoutly before in the meta, how to reduce the shock from having a question put on hold.

But at a very personal level, I find that people who get intimidated by a question put on hold should <strike>grow a pair</strike> work to develop their self steem. I always ask my friends that give up posting here after one suspended question whether they will give up coding too whenever some program they write fails due to a missing parameter.

Comment: None of that helps you much when your question is closed 30 minutes after you asked because it wasn't clear what was being asked and you weren't around to answer the comments asking for clarification.  I see this a lot now.  Questions are not left around for days waiting for the OP to make them into meaningful questions.

Comment: A good reason to get them right the first time.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question posted by a newbie, then closed for some reason, then reopened because the newbie poster followed a procedure to reopen it.  That's just one more thing the newbie doesn't know how to do.  So, saying that the newbie who didn't know to do thing 1 should just do thing 2 if their question is closed doesn't really help - they're newbies - they don't know these things.  My post is asking how do we educate new posters so they follow a better procedure in the first place so their question doesn't end up getting closed.

Comment: There is a description of the close reason, highlighted right below the question. With links. It goes something like **Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.** If the newbie can't bother to read that, then I doubt they would understand an answer that is not copypastable into their codebase anyway.

Comment: @Renan - Yes and by the time the question has been closed, the damage has been done.  A bunch of people on SO have wasted their time reading, trying to understand and generally interacting with the question.  The majority of people who will ever see this question are now gone and time has just been generally wasted.  The idea here is to help prevent at least some of that wastage rather than just let it happen and deal with it.  This is as much about the productivity of the SO community as it is about helping out the OP.

Comment: @jfriend00 This why a lot of instructors are reluctant to recommend using SO directly. It's NOT for newbie programmers. You have to get voted down a few times and have the tenacity to keep learning to eventually have good questions and provide acceptable answers. If SO really wants to be newbie friendly they would take your recommendations seriously and implement procedures like a ticking clock to encourage people to hang around so willing commenters can teach them the ropes. They have, at least, given lots of helpful suggestions at the, "Ask A Question."

Answer (score 10):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll answer.

I think Brock Adams and sharptooth are on the right track.  How can you let them know?  You tell them.

Not just buried in documentation, but you tell them as they try to post that it's in their best interest to hang around or periodically check for the next 30-60 minutes and why.  New users would get and acknowledge this tip at the very end of the question posting procedure.

sharptooth's comment:

> Can we perhaps have some kind of banner on the top of the just asked question which includes that after you post wording and only show it for people with little experience?

Brock's comment:

> How about one of those annoying onbeforeunload popups reading something like, "Please return to this page 30 minutes from now to check for answers or comments."

Comment: Yeah, an actual summary of positive suggestions instead of just arguments.

Comment: This is probably true, but there are *very many things* that (especially) a first-time poster must bear in mind in order to ask a good question. It might prove impractical for these to all be presented as they try to post -- emphasising one will de-emphasise others. I suppose there could be a "first question wizard", such that the relevant issues can be presented as a series of tasks/points. The longer the process, the more opportunity to present information, and if the information is necessary then (counter-intuitively) it's not inherently user-unfriendly to make it a big rigmarole.

Answer (score 6):

I think a part of good ol' netiquette is to get to know the community before you start posting. If you spend more than 10 minute on Stack Overflow, then you'll know that a question can be asked, edited twice, receive 6 comments, 5 downvotes, 2 answers and be closed within a couple of minutes, so it's a good idea to stick a around and see how your question develops.

If you are in such a hurry that you didn't have time to find this out, then you probably wouldn't close your browser anyway.

Apart from that, I don't think this is a problem that can or should be solved. Worst case, a question is closed while it didnt' need to be. OP can still take the text from the original question and improve it into a new question. Advantage of that, is that the new question will give them a new start, without the stress to update it while comments or downvotes keep pooring in and without the accumulated downvotes on the question.

Comment: So you don't think we should help people post better questions and better understand how SO works when they do post a question?  That's odd.  You must think that SO works flawlessly in this regard and no amount of effort to improve it is worthwhile.

Comment: Why is it odd? I think people should know that they have to learn the rules by observing. If I visit someone's house or join a new office, I don't put my feet on the table right away. I watch how other people behave and try to blend in. I don't need extra signs to remind me of that. Same on SO. If you just barge in and be a dick, then your question gets closed, no harm done. So I'm saying that SO is self cleaning and will educate people on the go. There is enough information to get started. People who do it wrong do so because they don't care. Rubbing it into their faces won't help.

Comment: I just think it's odd that when N% (where N is not a low number) of people do it wrong the first time or first few times, you think it's worth zero effort to help them do it better.  I guess you would rather they fail first (and waste other people's time in the SO community while doing so) than spend any effort to make it less likely they fail the first time.  Your method is one method of education, though most educators don't think that's the preferred method.  Yes, I agree it would be nice if they learned how SO works BEFORE they posted, but obviously many don't.  I'm hoping to change that.

Comment: The huge number of questions that can be closed as duplicate by just copying their title into the 'New question' box and copying the url to the first existing answer. Should you make the suggestions even bigger, bolder, redder, blinking? People are being helped such a lot already but they just won't see it. Maybe they are helped even too much.  It's as if they have lived in a rubber house with pillows on the floor, never learned to watch out for anything. And suddenly they bump their head against reality. So I don't think it's worthless, I just think it won't help. Fine by me if it would.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite active in the C# tag and this is such a common problem with newbies. It is really annoying so much people spend their time in the newbie, with apparently less interest from the one asking. (If I ask a question I am anxious to get the answer)

As told by others, I don't think you can fix this problem, since the problem is mostly in the person asking the question. Since this is a site for professionals, not for solving homework question, we can expect some professionalism from the one asking too. If their don't bother to read the How to ask, the close reason dialog, etc., why would we?

The ones taking this good will learn from it and ask a (hopefully better) question next time, the others who leave: let them leave. They are not the group deemed to be professionals.

Comment: The issue is that right now, it's set up such that a bunch of helpful people waste their time on an OP that isn't around.  And, we basically bash the OP the first time around (closing their question) and hope they learn from the bashing.  Many people believe that bashing them the first time isn't the most effective way of helping them learn and for someone who doesn't know how it works, it guarantees at least one bad experience for both the poster and those who first try to help.  I thought it would be worthwhile trying to lessen the number of bad experiences.

Comment: But isn't that just normal behavior? Is you ask your friend or coworker something, do you walk away then and come back half an hour later to get the answer?

Comment: That is the issue.  What you described is normal behavior in a conversation.  On the other hand, when you post a question to a mailing list or a forum, it's pretty normal behavior to post, go to sleep and then see what responses there are the next morning.  People posting here don't understand that SO is much more interactive (or capable of being much more interactive) than a mailing list.  And, with downvotes and voting to close a question, you have to be responsive or your question essentially gets kicked to the curb.  The idea here is to educate first time posters of this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to voice my own opinion for a moment as a user of SO:

Please be patient.

I understand that a site dedicated to providing quality answers to the questions of the world require a LOT of filtering and general cutting of the cruft. Nobody expects anything different.

If I were to ask a question on SO it would be because I've done my research and I'm stuck in the mud. But I have no clue what the turnaround time to my specific topic and problem are going to be. Will there be clarifying questions in 1 minute? 20? Will there be an answer in 5 minutes? Never? I may not be in a situation to keep tabs on the question's status because of something pressing. Does that mean my question is worthless because I had an hour meeting 10 minutes after I posted the question?

My point, I hope, is clear. This is a site dedicated to quality answers and I absolutely love it. But it is here because people need help, not overlords. Scolding and berating users (I came here because of OP's comment here:  [NodeJS: TypeError: undefined is not a function - Promise.all - Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898235/nodejs-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-promise-all-object-keys#comment78756842_45898235)) because they weren't working on other's perceptions of "reasonable amount of time" gives the entire community a bad rap. I had to wade through OP's vicious comments to find an answer that's useful. Is that behavior acceptable because the user left for two hours? He/She needed help.

Answer (score -1):

I'll take a stab at answering my own question.  It seems the issue is one of education for new posters about how they can maximize the chances that they will get a quality answer which is both beneficial to them and helps the productivity of the community.  As such, I can't see a better place to add something than when someone new is posting one of their first few questions.

So, here's a suggestion for a first time post screen:

1. When you've asked less than N questions that were not closed (perhaps maybe 5 or some small number, but probably more than just one) and someone presses the "Ask Question" button, they are taken to an introductory screen for new posters.
2. That introductory screen is given a title that sounds like it's your own best interests to read and is something like this: **"How to maximize the chances you get a good answer to your question?"**.
3. The introductory screen is short and sweet, not a lot of reading, with just the most salient points (each point can be linked to more info).  We want the new poster to actually see and read a couple of important bullet points.  It can contain a link to the [FAQ longer version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if someone so chooses to read more.  This page should not be a lot of reading by itself.
4. At the bottom of the screen is a button to "Start Writing My Question".
5. Here's a suggestion for the content on this screen (I'm not a writer so I'm sure the specific wording can be improved):

---

> **Tips for Maximizing the Chances You Will Get a Good Answer to Your
>   Question:**
>
> 1. **Write a good title** that summarizes the specific problem.  You want to attract people who know about your topic.
> 2. **Describe the actual problem you are trying to solve**, not just the solution you are stuck on.  People can give better answers is they know a bit of the bigger picture.
> 3. **Write a clear question** that will be meaningful to people who don't know anything about what you're doing.  If people don't
>      understand what you're asking, they won't be able to help.
> 4. **Include just enough code** to help others reproduce the problem and understand what you have tried.
> 5. **Include all relevant tags** so people watching only certain tags will be drawn to your question
> 6. **Then, after you post, keep that browser window open for the next 20-30 minutes** or come back to check on your question a couple
>      times.  If your question is not clear to some, people will post
>      comments asking for clarification of what you're asking.  In busy
>      forums, the majority of viewing and the majority of the activity on your post will be
>      shortly after you post it.  If your question isn't completely clear,
>      you need to see and respond quickly to avoid missing most of the
>      people who could or would help you.  This is not like a mailing list or most forums where you can just post and come back a long time later to see what responses there are.
> 7. **Use the Edit Link to Clarify Your Question**.  If you need to clarify or fix your question in any way, you can edit it to add/change the content at any time as many times as you like.
>
> If your question is not clear and your are not around to clarify it, **your question may get closed** because it was unclear what you were asking. Nobody wants this to happen, so be clear and **be responsive to questions asked in comments in the first 30-60 minutes after posting**.
>
> For more details on these points and even more tips for asking a good
>   question and getting a good answer, see [this page in the Help
>   Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
>
> **[[Start Writing My Question Now]]**

Comment: @PatrickHofman - isn't this Meta?

Comment: `tl;dr`. I think people who post crap won't read this, while people who do want to make an effort feel like they are not taken seriously by these self-evident rules. I'm a moderator on (another) community, and in my experience, some people do it right while others do it wrong. People that write bad titles will keep doing so, no matter how many times you improve the titles, instruct the posters, ask them, warn them. Sometimes they might learn in time, but a big bunch of text like this will not do the trick. Your intentions are good, but it won't work.

Comment: @GolezTrol - You've made it clear now that you think no efforts in this regard will do any good.  That's your opinion.  I'm not that cynical.  I'm sure there are some who don't care.  I think there are others who would gladly improve their chances of getting a better answer if they only knew what mattered.  I have evidence from a number of well intentioned newbies that they just assumed SO works like a mailing list - post now, come back tomorrow.  When informed that it's much more interactive than that, they were glad to operate differently.

Comment: I hate to be defeatist, because I really do support education efforts like this in spirit. I'm a huge proponent of education. But the *method* you're proposing simply doesn't work. @GolezTrol is right, and sadly it's not just his opinion. Studies have repeatedly shown that users do not read. *Especially* users having a frustrating problem and just trying to get their question answered. You can put up all the informative text that you want, but they'll see it as just extra hoops they need to jump through before they can post. As a result, they'll click through it as fast as possible.

Comment: ***However***, information like this should definitely be *made available* to people who seek it out. It won't be brand-new users who are looking for it, but people who have been around for a while. People who either have lurked without asking a question because they aren't sure of themselves, or people who *have* been around, *have* asked a few questions, and haven't had it go very well. Conscientious people of that type will be looking for how to improve themselves. And information on how needs to be made available. That's the discussion  here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/

Comment: @CodyGray - please post a reference link to these studies that show that there is nothing that can be done to educate a newbie user in any way before they post.  I'd like to see that study.  Though you seem to have already given up, I'm not willing to believe that nothing can be done to improve things at least a bit.

Answer (score -15):

Perhaps apply a script that will scan the question for code, and if the question does not meet some minimum requirement, have a popup that says something in the nature:

Your question only contains x lines of code in it. If you feel that your question has sufficient clarity and detail to be understood, click "Proceed", otherwise please add more detail to help responders get to the core of you what you are asking.

Although, the amount of code in a question certainly does not guarantee clarity.

Maybe categorize the questions, as in "theory", "code assist", etc. where the poster checks a box to select which category the question belongs and if it's a code assist, require that they post their code!! :)

Comment: This issue is about clarity of question, not about how many lines of code are present.  There is zero correlation between the two.

Comment: This would only lead to people abusing the wrong category in order to circumvent the clarity check. Also I don't think there is any algorithm that could make that check accurate.

Comment: Wow...talk about casting stones for a suggestion!! Thanks everyone. I don't see anyone else with suggestions. All I see are more arguments. Like to see what someone else suggests. Talk about intimidating the newbies...a thanks but no thanks would have sufficed

Comment: Sorry if you think people are casting stones. Even though I appreciate you thinking about it and trying to find a way to make everything better, I disagree with the suggestion. Also, don't worry about being downvoted on meta, it does not really hurt and teaches one to grow a thicker skin. 6-inch steel-plates should be enough ;-)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why people think this is such a bad idea, if applied sparingly and properly with a smart script. I don't think it would lead to abuse, seeing as all you have to do to "circumvent" the script is to "click 'Proceed'", as Scott said. After all, this question is not about hard limitations or rule changes, but rather a way to make inexperienced users _aware_ of clarity requirements and/or  the necessity of staying around their question. (Just my 2¢)

Comment: Thanks Deduplicator...it's quite alright. I'm not insecure about offering my ideas, however good or bad they may be ;-)

Comment: @raxod502 *if applied sparingly and properly with a smart script* Much easier said than done. See http://xkcd.com/1319/

Comment: Downvotes are not "casting stones". Voting is the way you show agreement or disagreement. If you agree with an answer, think it is particularly insightful, or think it is helpful, you vote it up. If you disagree with an answer, think it contributes nothing new to the discussion, or it is wrong, then you vote it down. This one, for me, falls into the "disagree" category. I don't think it is a good idea. So -1. I don't think any less of you for proposing it, of course. We appreciate all input that we can get. Downvotes don't mean "go away".