# Asking about the existence of a particular technique without being Too Broad... "Is it Possible?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

My question was put on hold as too broad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397526/move-files-on-a-remote-machine-without-copying

I think if I had just asked how to move files over the network with C# then it would have been easy for someone to answer and I seriously doubt it would have ever gotten flagged. But I actually asked a more specific question than that so I'm wondering whether this was accurately marked as 'too broad' or if the reason was really different and that specification was just the closest.

I also wonder if it would have been put on hold had I included a piece of code.  But I don't know any method for copying files that could do what I want... in fact I'm trying to find out if there even *is* a method for doing what I want.

It seems to me that the question of whether it's possible to 'move' files on a remote machine is pretty specific, but if there's something I could do to make it more specific please let me know.

Comment: Sadly, you might have gotten a better response if you'd pretended to be really ignorant. "I am trying to rename files in C# but File.Move doesn't accept network paths / takes too long and the hard disk works like crazy". Asking "is there a suitable screwdriver?" seems undesired here, but waving crazily with a hammer at the screw will for sure get you helpful suggestions.

Comment: @jdm Actually someone responded with 'exactly' what I needed to hear in the comments, but thanks for your two cents ;)

Comment: It appears you were asking without any specific programming language in mind, aka you were *too broad*.

Answer (score 52):

### Is it possible?

Questions that start or end with the phrase "Is it possible" are ultimately uninteresting to the Stack Overflow community, for a number of reasons:

1. It's almost always possible, if you have enough time and money. Usually, you don't state in your question how much time and money you have.
2. The real question being asked is either "can it be done in a practical way," which is often too subjective to answer definitively, or "is there a tool that can do it" which makes it an off-topic product recommendation question, or "can i haz some codez," which makes it a work order.
3. Asking "is it possible" is a cop-out.  You don't have to do any research or critical thinking to ask such a question.  It's a hand-waving, Hail-Mary pass, throwing spaghetti against the wall to see if any will stick.

### So how to fix it?

1. Explain your problem in sufficient clarity and detail that your question becomes answerable.
2. Show us your research.  What have you tried, and why didn't it work for you?  This avoids us having to repeat your Google searches and investigations, if you indeed performed any.
3. Be specific about what kind of solution you want. Saying
   "Is it possible" and hoping that someone will throw you a bone is the wrong approach.

**Further Reading**
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes! Canonical-grade answer prompted by a [specific-question] post. This is the SE way to do mentoring.

Comment: This question has several other issues, of course, and isn't salvageable without OP's clarification.  But it'd be cool if people would fix these sorts of errors in salvageable questions using the 'edit' button rather than trying to push them away with the 'close' button.  ("Is it possible?"  Almost automatically crap.  "How do I do this?"  There's the interesting question.  Making the crap question interesting is pretty much a mechanical transformation.)

Comment: @tmyklebu Your "mechanical transformation" skips all of the "how to fix it" steps. If you ask "how do I do X" without research or specifics, it's a bad question.

Comment: @murgatroid99: I do not believe I claimed that said mechanical transformation fixes *all* crap questions.  Lots of questions are wholly unsalvageable.  There are enough that can be rendered acceptable by tweaking the phrasing like that, though, and it's trivial to fix them instead of closing them.

Comment: Granted. But the problem is that "Is it possible" is more often an **indicator** of crap than it is the only negative quality of the question. In the "indicator" case, changing the phrase won't make the question good, and otherwise the question is probably OK without the change. If I asked "Is it possible to do X with framework Y in context Z, and A didn't work for reason B?" that's not a bad question and doesn't need the edit. If I asked "Is it possible to send an image over the internet?" then the question needs research and clarification, not rewording.

Comment: @tmyklebu shouldn't it be the OPs responsibility to provide a non-un-salvageable question in the first place? Once it's put on hold then that just adds to the OPs motivation to edit it themself and their edit will automatically place the question in the reopen-queue (which unlike the close-queue is usually empty).

Comment: @murgatroid99: You're allowed to read the entire question before voting, rather than looking for 'key words' and 'indicators' and such.  Enough people just look for the 'indicators.'  Like I said, I'm not defending the particular question being discussed here.

Comment: @ivarni: Again, if a question's garbage, you should close it.  I'm only addressing the case where a question fits some close reason because of an accident of wording.

Comment: Gold plate this answer.  No, better, cast it in bronze and then cast it at the heads of people who ask "is it possible?" questions.

Comment: Wow, this is like somebody asking "do you have a watch?" and the other person saying "yes" and walking on...

Comment: @jdm I would say it is more like somebody asking *is it possible to tell the time?*