# How to review "is this possible" questions

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was reviewing First Posts when one question appeared that looked something like this:

> I'm using framework X on CMS Y. I want to perform operation Z so I can show a certain desired result.
>
> Is this possible?

I suppose this question is not appropriate for StackOverflow, but I'm not sure how to flag it. The OP is not asking for a recommendation or advice on a specific problem, just asking if something is possible or not.

What is the best way of reviewing this type of questions?

**EDIT**

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896969/dj-classifieds-adverts-item-images-dose-not-open-in-a-slim-box#comment47920253_29896969):

> I am using DJ-Classifieds (ver. 2.5) in Joomla 2.5.7. I would like to
>   show all images of an advert item in a slim box plug-in.
>
> Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I tried the approach presented by null: I believe it makes sense to change the user's question to a "how to", since it is probably his/her intentions anyway.

The only change I made was turning

> Is it possible?

Into

> How can I accomplish this?

However, my edit was approved by 2 users but rejected by 3 users for the following reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I believe these kind of edits are not welcome by the community and don't represent a good solution for this problem.

**UPDATE 2**

This question was

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking

Which I find ironic because I'm asking specifically how to review/flag a particular type of question.

In the answers and comments, users are telling me to flag it as "unclear" although the question is as clear as possible (Yes/No). Now my question is flagged as unclear although I'm asking for something specific.

Someone suggested my question was unclear because I didn't provide an example. So I did provide an example (one of a few I already encountered as a reviewer), but still my question gets flagged.

I believe something is not working right with this kind of flagging. If I'm asking something quite specific and I get my question flagged as "unclear", I get confused as a user and I'm not sure what more can I do.

As a conclusion, flagging clear questions ("Is this possible?") as unclear is definitely not the solution. I suppose there's a gap in the flagging options.

Comment: I would go for either too broad or unclear.

Comment: @GrantWinney In the most recent example I faced, a user just stated that his desired result was "to output images into the plugin". Unsurprisingly the first comment was "Humanity has landed on the moon, sure it's possible! Show us what you have tried so far". I agree the community doesn't receive these questions that well, and I understand why.

Comment: @rene The desired answer is actually very clear and specific. I suppose that if the answer is positive, the user will want to know how to do it, but that's not what he is asking at the moment. If the objective is to flag I agree with your POV, but we should at least try to flag it correctly as a good practice.

Comment: There's no close reason that fits "Is this possible" when it is a clear question with enough information to answer it. I'd rather see the question edited to "How can i accomplish this?" so that it may at least be somewhat helpful to someone if it does receive an answer. Still downvote worthy though due to lack of research.

Comment: This question is too vague and lacks specific examples. Simply using the words "is this possible" should have no significant impact on the rest of a question.

Comment: see  **[Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)**

Comment: There is a Meta answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269359/2144390) that I bookmarked a while ago. When I vote to close a vague/broad question I often link to it in my comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking about the existence of a particular technique without being Too Broad... "Is it Possible?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269352/asking-about-the-existence-of-a-particular-technique-without-being-too-broad)

Answer (score 5):

I guess asking "**how to** do Z with X on Y" is a good question for SO.
Asking the "how to" question includes the "is it possible" question.

I do not think it is too broad if X, Y and Z a clearly defined. And it isn't unclear either. I agree to what people say in the comments: An "Is it possible..." question is not bad per se.

I'd say just reword the question to the "how to" form.

Admittedly, it expands the question, but it also expands any possible answer and makes them useful for those looking for an answer to the "how to" question. The motivation could be to find out if a certain technology is suitable for a certain goal (and I think that is a very valid question to ask here) but more often, such questions are basically "how to" questions in the first place anyway.

A lonely "yes" or "no" is generally not considered a good answer, both by SO standards and by what the asker expects. You'd have to show some prove to make it a valid answer and that is usually the same as answering the "how to" question.

Given the example:

> I am using DJ-Classifieds (ver. 2.5) in Joomla 2.5.7. I would like to
>   show all images of an advert item in a slim box plug-in.
>        Is it possible?

I'd change it to

> How do I show all images of an advert item in a slim box plug-in
>   using DJ-Classifieds (ver. 2.5) in Joomla 2.5.7?

The question is too specific to be just asking for the possibility.
**I think it actually shows some effort by including all version numbers properly.** On the contrary, there is **no apparent research effort** in the question. If for anything, it should be closed for a lack of research effort.

An improved question could look like this (added some pseudo research effort):

> How do I show all images of an advert item in a slim box plug-in using
>   DJ-Classifieds (ver. 2.5) in Joomla 2.5.7?
>
> I went to the Joomla club last night to check out Classifieds' skills
>   on the turn tables, but oh boy his vibes are for grannies. I asked all
>   around how they got the images of the ads into the slim boxes but
>   nobody could tell me. I even spilled my drink on the mixer of that clown
>   of a wanna-be DJ to make him stop ruining everybody's night with his
>   crappy mu**sick** and to concentrate more on my questions. Immediately
>   two helpful looking guys arrived but it turns out they could not
>   answer my question either and in fact threw me out of that club WTF?

I obviously have no idea what the question is all about but this is meta and you get the point.

Comment: This all to much meta but I'm not convinced that `X on Y, needing R by doing Z` is the same as `How to do Z with X on Y`. Because if Z with X on Y gives fubar you changed the question.

Comment: @rene If it isn't possible, it's still answerable with "This isn't possible, and here's why" or "This isn't possible, but this other thing is." Asking how to do something always includes the is it possible question.

Comment: @KevinB yes, that's what I was trying to say

Comment: @rene sorry for the confusion. I left out R (being the result, I assume). I suggested that `Is it possible to get R by doing Z with X on Y?` could be replaced by `How do I get R by doing Z with X on Y?`

Comment: That helps a bit but if Z is a full set of functionalities I don't see how you think it is not too broad.

Comment: @rene good point, but I think Z cannot be _that_ broad given R. I think the broadness does not stem from the "possibility?" style of question but what Z and R are. (_that 'R are' was kind of funny to read, isn't it?_)

Comment: What if R is forum, Z plugins and Y wordpress? I know we are discussing this on meta but the question we are trying to answer is so meta in itself that is hard to come-up with something that fits. That is the reason I started with a comment on the question first. But I really think this and the other answer are leaving out a whole bunch of options. If this guidance gets adopted we are open for a flood of broad questions.

Comment: @rene in this case, the question would be too broad/unclear indeed, but that's not because of the "is it possible?" way it is asked. I think this question is about the style of the questions, not their content.

Comment: _"I do not think it is too broad if X, Y and Z a clearly defined"_ -- it's plausible the question wouldn't be "too broad", but _highly_ unlikely. In the vast majority of cases I've seen, the literal answer to the question "is it possible" can be only "yes" or "no". Reinterpreting the question as something else is fruitful only if that something else is a reasonably specific question, but in my experience that's pretty much never the case. "Is it possible" almost always is connected with a question that also insufficiently narrows the scope of the problem.

Comment: In your edit you put `Joomla` in backticks. You do know that [this is horrible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right), right ?

Comment: @JonasCz no I didn't, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score -1):

[The linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896969/dj-classifieds-adverts-item-images-dose-not-open-in-a-slim-box) is framed in such a way that:

1. One can't say it is too broad. An answer of "yes" or "no" would be sufficient.
2. One can't say it is based on opinion either. It can either be done or it can't be done.
3. It does not show any research effort on the part of the user.
4. Knowing the answer to the question will not add any value to SO users.

I would vote to close the question on the last two grounds.

A more useful question will be:

I looked at 'X'. I looked at 'Y'.

I didn't find anything there that gives me a clear answer. Should I look somewhere else for a clearer answer.

or

I think I should use strategy 'A' given what I have read. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Vote to close the question, but how to flag it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the answer the question could fit into any number of flags. But seems to be primarily `Off Topic` or:

1. Too Broad
2. Primarily Opinion Based

However this is also against the actual question. If it is quite clear what the user is trying to achieve and they have provided an example of what they are doing then I would flag it as `Off Topic` as the user has already created an example and knows the result.

If they have not provided any details and are simply asking the community to simulate the result for them I would flag this as `Off Topic -> Why isnt this working`

Comment: If the question is worded in a way that it's basically asking for a yes/no answer, isn't it more like "not broad enough" than "too broad"?

Answer (score -2):

The answer on that question would either be Yes, No or Depends. Which makes the question not useful and therefor open for downvotes. To prevent that experience for the OP it is vital to get the best fitting close reason on that question as quickly as possibile.

The following reasons apply:

- unclear
  Use this reason if you have knowledge of Z which a simple often used function. When closed as unclear the following notice is shown to the OP

  > Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

  This is the correct information for the OP to improve the question.
- too broad
  Use this reason if Z is a complete subset of functionalities with all kind of booby-traps and nasty behavior involved. This this message for the OP when closed:

  > There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

  This is the correct notice for the OP because by adding details and focus on their problem they zoom-in on their actual problem that might as well be useful for later readers.