# Does the current downvote system incentivize improvement of poor questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, mentoring

Recently there was an excellent featured question asking whether this site can help mentor new users: [Can we make this meta site work for mentoring?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring). This got me thinking about the chain of events surrounding a poor question from a user who means well.

Initially, the poor state of the question will attract a number of downvotes. This is fine and quite proper. So now the OP is looking at a question with a score of `-5` and hopefully some helpful comments encouraging improvement. The OP then improves the question, perhaps using meta for some guidance. We now have an acceptable question, sitting at `-5`.

If the OP interacts with the community here, the "meta effect" may cause the question to gain a positive score. But otherwise, the question is unlikely to get above `0` for a number of reasons:

- Chances are it's not a work of genius. It's just a solid question now.
- Question upvotes are rare on many tags.
- The negative score will remove the question from several views on the site.

The original casters of the downvotes are long gone. We can't expect them to hang around on the off-chance this question gets improved; let's be honest, few do. But for the ones that do, we have a system here that permanently scars them with a negative score that's incredibly hard to shift.

Hopefully, this experience will teach the OP and future questions won't suffer in the same way. But it's possible this first question is going to remain unanswered due to its score. It also may leave a sour taste in the mouth of an OP who took the time to improve their question.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this situation? Do we need to worry about it? Are there any changes to the site that might alleviate the issue? It feels like the system isn't set up to incentivize the improvement of poor questions.

Comment: If up-votes on questions are so rare, could they have more weight on a heavily down-voted question after an edit? Bad question `->` `score -5` `->` `*question edit*` `->` `*upvote (+2)*` `->`  `score -3` `->` `*upvote (+2)*` `->` `score -1` `->` `*upvote (+1)*` `->` `score 0`. Do a few up-votes in a row, after a heavily down-voted question has been edited, indicate that the question is at least acceptable now and worthy of a quick bump up to 0?

Comment: I agree that this is probably happening, yes. I don't know whether there's a solution for it. If the question got closed and enters a reopen review queue, reviewers should maybe upvote it more if it's deserved?

Comment: @misterManSam Not a bad idea. I was musing on a plan where a significant edit could throw the question into a queue where people vote on wiping the slate clean.

Comment: It would be nice to hear some counter viewpoints from the down-voters :-)

Comment: Once the question is edited, that queue is effectively the front page. Give the first new visitors a bigger hammer and the problem might solve itself. I agree that down-votes are a deterrent to a good edit and new visitors do take them personally.

Comment: The thing is, though, that once a question starts garnering upvotes, they also get the rep to go with it.  That, right there, is a pretty positive marker.  It shows that listening to (and using!) feedback gives rewards.  Ok, so your question is still at -1.  But you now have 20 rep, and people can see the question again.

Comment: I've always thought it would be a good idea to notify users who downvote a question or answer when it's been updated (just once), so they know when they can revisit it and possibly reverse their downvote.

Comment: -5 is very bad indeed. An other option would be for the OP to close the bad old question to ask a better one?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-physics-arxiv-blog/data-mining-reveals-how-the-down-vote-leads-to-a-vicious-circle-of-negative-feedback-aad9d49da238

Comment: @snailboat +1 that is a very interesting read.

Comment: @snailboat Interesting that there's been a study about negative voting. The linked article seems to assume causality between votes and future behaviour - I can only hope the paper proves this somehow otherwise the results mean little.

Comment: @snailboat That paper says that the downvotes don't serve a deterrent effect for the recipient. I don't find that difficult to believe. It does, however, make a *great* argument for why we need to use vote counts to *block* users who consistently receive downvotes from contributing altogether.

Comment: May be we could add the *tendancy* to the current score of up-down votes. So, when we see a -5 question in front page **but recently upvoted** it would be a clue that is may be worth reading because it was improved. Currently I admit I not even look questions under -2

Answer (score 22):

> Are there any changes to the site that might alleviate the issue?

This problem isn't unique to poor questions, but poor answers too, and I think there's a way to fix it nearly instantly:

**Allow downvoters a way to tell when a post is edited**.

When a question is closed, then edited, it goes into the Reopen queue to ask people if it's worth reopening, we should do something similar with downvoted posts (Questions and Answers, as the same should be true of both), in one of two ways:

1. Create an **Improved Posts Queue**.
   This would contain a queue of every post you've downvoted which have been subsequently edited, presented in diff style. The user would then see the post with the up and down vote buttons so you can either remove the downvote, upvote or leave it as it is, like **First Posts** and **Later Answers** as well as a <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>, <kbd>Done</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd> buttons to control the queue.

   This would obviously require some tweaks to prevent spamming, for example a certain percentage of the post which would have to be added, edited or removed in order to trigger it being recognised as a large enough edit to fix major issues with the post.
2. Send notifications to the users through the Inbox Messages.
   I'm less fond of this idea due to the amount of messages heavy voters would get, but it could work in theory.

I try and do this, but the only way to do it at the moment is to favourite the question and watch for edits, but this sends the wrong message (It's not a favourite, I just need to keep track of it) and isn't feasible if you downvote a lot.

Comment: Edit != "improved"

Comment: @bjb568 But it can, and the cases where it doesn't is why I said it would include a `No Action Needed` button.

Comment: Fine, so I go thru a queue without a button for negative action? Seems useless.

Comment: @bjb568 `No Action Needed` is the negative button in this case, it means the edit was not helpful.

Comment: The words you use for your proposal are likely to give the wrong impression to people reading quickly. When you say "notify" people will think "inbox" because that's how people usually understand the word "notify" (i.e. a message showing up in your inbox). But you suggest the use of the inbox only in your 2nd item. Using the inbox for this, BTW, has been suggested dozens of times, and is a no-go, because a lot of edits don't actually fix the post to an extent that warrant a vote reversal.

Comment: And I'm also against the idea of a queue. In one of the many discussions we've had a about it I mentioned that what I would support is having the capability in my profile to have a list of questions that have been edited after I voted (up, down, vote-to-close, whatever) and then I have the choice to look at whichever one I want. I can't support anything more intrusive.

Comment: @MrLore I have 884 outstanding down votes when I dig into what votes are still there.  I dread the possibility that edits on these would trigger hundreds of notifications as people tweak "a" to "`a`" and "java" to "Java" in attempts to get additional attention for it.

Comment: @Louis Good point, I've changed the wording slightly in accordance with your advice. Hopefully I'll be `rewarded by the community in the form of not getting downvoted more!` And what do you mean about a queue being intrusive? The only queue which can be seen without clicking on the Review button is suggested edits.

Comment: @MrLore "Intrusive" was not the best choice of word. Queues take you by the hand and lead you through posts one by one. A list (just like the lists we have when we click on our profiles now) does not do that. You're free to look at whatever you want in the list.

Comment: @MichaelT I've also added in a line to deal with that- however the same criticism could be levelled at the Reopen queue.

Comment: The Reopen queue has 5 entries (as of this writing) in it that can be handled by anyone with sufficient reputation.  Once its out of the queue, its done.  A 'past vote improvement' queue - how often would that trigger when they change "a" to "`a`" on one day and then "java" to "Java" a week later, and then a week later a complete rewrite of the question? Why? What logic would be based on that?  Now, one *might* argue that 'votes' needs to be able to be sorted not just by when the vote was cast, but by "activity" as the favorites tab can... but a queue and notifications would be painful.

Comment: @MrLore and FWIW, I've tossed this idea into a feature request over on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238512/213963).

Comment: If there's a queue that will potentially let you regain reputation, it will be abused.

Comment: @bjb568 How? If the users knew each other, they never would have downvoted them to begin with. The fact that you can only change your vote after the post has been edited is for exactly this situation.

Comment: @MrLore No, it's like ***Y U NO UNDO DOWNVOTE !@#$ YOU $%^ EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT***

Comment: @bjb568 Pointlessly editing your post to bump it is already against the rules and Moderators can lock your post if you do it.

Comment: So obviously the moderators don't have enough work and we need to make a system to give them more by incentivizing abusive behavior.

Comment: This is a great idea, especially when you take into account the fact that few posts actually get modified. Risk of abuse would be minimal for the same reason. If you remove the downvote from an answer, you could get your one rep back. I wouldn't put any extra incentive on it. The "filter by Levenshtein distance (or similar)" would be an absolute must, though.

Comment: @MrLore Why on earth wouldn't users who know each other use downvotes?  I don't see your logic.  I sometimes downvote my friends.  It's about the question or the answer, not about who wrote it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Abusing the system.

Answer (score -2):

I agree completely.  Many new users are not initially interested in asking a robust, well-written piece of literature that will add substantial value to the community and has such quality that it could be cited in a Wikipedia article (we do have high standards and that is a good thing).  They are interested in solving a problem (be it for business or for pleasure) and have found the users of this site to be good "solvers of problems".

In the case you describe however, it seems to me to have a "forgiveness" feature for **NEW** users (existing users *really* have no excuse) who do respond to feedback and attempt to improve their question.  I know mods already have a lot on their plate but maybe a system could be worked out that would put these types of questions in a queue that a moderator (or high rep user) can review and if they decide that the question has been improved enough, that person could "forgive" the questioner and remove the downvotes (technical implementation details notwithstanding) to clear the slate.

Obviously we'd have to work some details out such as: reverting the forgiveness if after review the question continues to be downvoted, what to do with the lost rep (if any) from the downvotes, how this would affect the vote-counts of the downvoters, etc...

---

But I think with this, many goals (of the site and the OP) could be met:

- The community is improved by having fewer poor quality questions
- The OP is rewarded for effort to improve (which re-enforces the behavior)
- The queue would draw attention to these cases so they don't go unnoticed
- The "negative" user-experience is lessened
- Doesn't have any effect on poor quality questions (and their perpetrators) that are not revised

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Queue exists. It's called the "reopen queue", accessible if you have 3k rep.

Comment: Wouldn't that only affect closed questions (not just downvoted ones)?  Does the re-open queue reverse the downvotes?

Comment: No, it reopens closed questions.

Comment: I see your point.  It seems to me however, that it serves a different enough purpose to warrant a separate mechanism (not necessarily a queue). Particularly for "wiping out" downvotes that after a question has been modified are now invalid due to a substantially changed context.

Comment: One could certainly add a list to the profile: Questions you downvoted which might have improved sufficiently, in which all questions you downvoted will be put after any edit. Bonus points for an extra-indicator: Received more/no downvotes and no upvotes after the edit putting it there.

Answer (score -7):

1. Well, you posted a bad question and wasted people's time. That can't be undone.
2. Not only should you feel good helping the community, you also get rewarded by the community in the form of not getting downvoted more!
3. This isn't really a problem anyway, since most well-meaning users read the faq or have basic observational skills and won't ask *that* bad of questions anyway

Comment: _"you posted a bad question and wasted people's time. That can't be undone"_ I agree particularly with that part. I would add we spend time both trying to understand the original question -- and trying to help improving things for people that too often don't care...

Comment: All of these points seem focused on punishing the user (for wasting people's time, etc.).  Shouldn't the focus be on the current state of the question?  A good question with a score of -5 is an unfortunate state of affairs, regardless of how it's impacted anyone's reputation.

Comment: your second point doesn't make sense, because if an improvement to a  question is being ignored due to low traffic, you probably also don't have the traffic to get you downvoted more, and you also probably don't have the traffic to meaningfully help the community by improving your question.

Comment: @femtoRgon Well, this question is about incentivisation, so yes, I'm focusing on the user.

Comment: and your third point is just dismissing the entire concept of improving your post all together.

Comment: @SamIam Unless you've gone under -4 (your question is really awful or you were really slow with a fix), it'll be bumped.

Comment: @SamIam The problem is that now-improved posts are overlooked, point 3 addresses that by stating it's a relatively rare case. It isn't that improving your post doesn't affect views or is useless, it's that most people either don't edit their bad questions or don't ask bad questions in the first place.

Comment: @femtoRgon _"All of these points seem focused on punishing the user"_ I don't understand it that way. When the OP fixes the issues with his question decently fast and decently well, there is no reason for reaching a score of -4 or less. Moreover, if OP replies to comments requesting improvements, there is a chance for us to revise a down-vote. Maybe I missed the point of this answer, but if _none_ of those things are done, and the edit is just to make the question "less worst" -- I don't see the point in doing OP some favor.