# Is the Reversal badge making you chase low hanging fruit? et al

Tags: discussion

Ok so differing from the [Get rid of the Reversal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277576/get-rid-of-the-reversal-badge) & [Doesn't the [Reversal] badge go against community consensus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272596/doesnt-the-reversal-badge-go-against-community-consensus) discussions.

Does the reversal badge make you go after low hanging fruit?

The badge is pretty hard to get and it takes some difficulty to find the right question where it *isn't* bad enough its going to be closed but is easy/poor enough it will get the right amount of down votes

Now after looking for a while for potential candidates to answer I came across this one this morning [UTF-8 nvarchar Romanian letters not displaying in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504844/utf-8-in-sql-server-2012/30506174#30506174) which was fitting of the criteria above and its just a case of fingers crossed and biding time to see if my answer gets up voted.

However if i hadn't of come across that i would still be looking, which brings me to my discussion point(s).

People who want this badge (or have it), are(did) you looking(look) for these(that) questions(question) or are you waiting to(did you) come across it naturally.

Bonus question, if you up voted a question and it was sitting at `-3` and you had answered it and had `20` or more up votes, would you down vote it for the badge?

Comment: What exactly is low-hanging about a -3 question, other than its score?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Low hanging meaning easy to answer, question could have been googled by the OP etc

Comment: @Matt or the other more likely situation that the question is unclear or not useful (and somehow not closed).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yeah exactly

Comment: I see a reversal badge as a small reward for the person who encounters a  poorly-written question, but understands what the OP means and provides a well-written, comprehensive answer anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Absolutely, as i said i'm not questioning the badge, i'm discussing the way people approach to getting the badge

Comment: FWIW: I have not really gone out of my way to get *any* badges. I don't know how many people do. That'd be an interesting survey in itself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's certainly what it *should* be, and in the best cases also is. There are many cases (I think actually more cases) where it certainly isn't though.

Comment: @deceze - There have been a few meta questions on the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges which implies that those are badges people put in an effort to get those. But there are very few badges that you can pursue that way since most depend on how the community responds to your actions, including this one.