# Getting information on downvoted questions that were changed after vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen a poorly written question ([IP address to hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248002/ip-address-to-hostname)) which needed some comments to bring it into a proper form (I think that question is ok - not really really great question, but it's ok now).

But in the mean time the question got downvoted several times.

**Are the users who downvoted informed about the change?** I mean, if they would read the question **now** I'm pretty sure they wouldn't vote down.

Is there a mechanism that delivers information to the users? Or is it not the way it was meant to be?

I'm not sure how to handle such situation.

Comment: I think I've seen a similar question before; I'll try to dig it up. The tl;dr is "no."

Comment: yes thanks, i was not able to find one, but honestly: it's hard to find a simialr question because you can ask that question in dozend different ways!! if you are experienced you **know** the question here and i'm glad i met such a man/woman!

Comment: I'm not too surprised; there's a surprisingly large number of questions like these that are hard to find. The end goal though is to have a clear and helpful answer, whether here or in a linked question. :)

Comment: (And for the record, I'm male)

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c) question from MSE summarize it enough? I can resummarize it here if people prefer (I'm still a little hazy about what the norm is with MSO/MST cross-site dupes)

Comment: well, if the answer is **NO** then you don't have to put tooooooo much effort into finding that answer/question ... i'm glad i know the answer now (although i don't like it, haha)!  thanks again *man* ^_^

Comment: argh too fast, you were too fast!!  (i'm sooo slow today :-$ )

Comment: Don't worry too much about not liking that it doesn't exist. Judging from the score for the question I linked, you're definitely not alone.

Comment: yes, that is totally my question! i'm astound that even grandmaster Jon Skeet had the same idea...

Comment: [This is also a relevant discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269524/does-the-current-downvote-system-incentivize-improvement-of-poor-questions)

Comment: @misterManSam yes, that is exactly my point, thanks for finding that thread!! (as mentioned above it's really really hard to find such a question, because it can be described in dozend ways)... thanks for the link!!

Comment: @MartinFrank - No worries :) I do think that there should be a mechanism in place to incentivise question improvement, such as lending more weight to upvotes on a heavily downvoted question. I've seen posts get to around -3 or worse simply because the OP didn't indent their HTML properly (so it didn't show and looked like a poor question) and didn't fix it quickly enough. That is very unfair.

Comment: @misterManSam i've noticed the same - i really feel bad for those people, mostly they are new to stackoverflow and that's not a fair way to be welcomened... the ultimate gaol for my question would be to implement a feature that fixes this... see tag [feature-request]....

Comment: @misterManSam can you ask a Moderator/Admin to reset the score of a question?

Comment: @MartinFrank - I'm pretty sure there is no system to reset a questions score... votes should be community consensus.

Comment: @misterManSam do you think you should be able to flag a question then? flag for reset? i know that it doesn't exist yet, but maybe i'm toooooo enthusiatic or to naive to fully understand what such a flag would mean?

Comment: @MartinFrank - A flag wouldn't make sense because any changes would again require community consensus (multiple votes for a "reset") - might as well just upvote :p

Comment: @misterManSam upvote - that's what i do... and i think you are right, thats the only thing left to do...

Comment: [This is my idea from that other post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269524/does-the-current-downvote-system-incentivize-improvement-of-poor-questions#comment83300_269524) - "If upvotes on questions are so rare, could they have more weight on a heavily downvoted question after an edit? `Bad question -> score -5 -> *question edit* -> *upvote (+2)* -> score -3 -> *upvote (+2)* -> score -1 -> *upvote (+1)* -> score 0.` Do a few upvotes in a row, after a heavily down-voted question has been edited, indicate that the question is at least acceptable now and worthy of a quick bump up to 0?"

Comment: @Louis yes, it seems like a duplicate - as several times mentioned above it's hard to find this question because there are a dodzend ways to ask the same question! it's still good to have your link on the discussion so other might find themself better around here!!! thank you!!!