# If machine learning is as good as the industry says why do we need humans to "filter" posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I find myself wondering what can really be done to reduce the anxiety associated with putting out a question just to see three attempts to close for each person willing to actually respond with a answer or at least a clarifying question.

I figure relegating question closing almost entirely to machine learning could at least reduce the burden of curating the forums for the mods if not also improve the general tone of conversation within users as they might just approached things from a different angle (knowing that there is already an algorithm to remove invalid questions). But the more I think about it the more I worry that someone is probably already implementing their own best implementation and casting votes through bot accounts.

I can think of several arguments why not: you might need to train models for something like this on some human generated training data; models fail and you need people to review the errors; and finally I don't want to see Stack Exchange fundamentally change. But I think it might have to because if A.I. might be good enough that we start to worry about people being robots we need better robots on our side.

**Links from review:**

- [Does the current downvote system incentivize improvement of poor questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269524/does-the-current-downvote-system-incentivize-improvement-of-poor-questions)
- [Does Stack Overflow use machine learning for posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359665/does-stack-overflow-use-machine-learning-for-posts)

**EDIT**

Looking over responses and and seeing the question closed I have to add; I believe the conversation about how these technologies could be used to evolve respondents ability to satisfy askers' needs needs to be open somewhere or else this community will continue to denigrate more and more good intentioned posts into oblivion like this one.

Comment: *"If machine learning is as good as the industry says..."* Well, there's your problem. You started from a false premise. There is an automatic comment flagger (mod-only) that is based around machine learning. It's absolutely terrible. Most of the time, it's worse than simply *randomly* flagging comments. We definitely do not need more of this kind of "intelligence".

Comment: We are cheaper. Nothing beats a free lunch.

Comment: What do you mean "we", human? Muhuhahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: I find surreal that this post would be off-topic.

Answer (score 17):

Machine learning for evaluating content quality [has been tried](https://www.vice.com/en/article/pa7dj9/flawed-algorithms-are-grading-millions-of-students-essays).  It sucks.

It thinks gibberish with fancy words is great or even perfect, and this is the state of the art for a company trying to sell this as its only product.  There's no way Stack Exchange could, on the side, build a machine-learning algorithm that can *reliably* tell the difference between an insightful question that no one has asked before, and the 10,000th duplicate of *What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?*

Sure, it could help.  We could probably warn people when their questions need improvement to reduce the number of people who experience their question being closed.  Heck, [I've advocated for Stack Overflow doing just that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399854/208273).  But we're not going to be able to replace human review anytime soon, because computers just aren't that smart.

Comment: Well duplicate questions are technically "good"... but it's duplicate xd

Comment: @Alviandoh at some point, asking the same question for the n-thousandth time ceases to be "good", because there were so many opportunities for the asker to find any of the _other_ duplicates that they clearly did not put any effort into their question, but rather wants Stack Overflow to do all of their work for them without creating anything useful for anyone else.  I've seen good, new `NullPointerException` questions (usually involving a pattern of error or a framework crash), but they are few and far between.  They also wouldn't be duplicates of that question.

Comment: Maybe if we have a lot of actual super good questions grouped together... but compared that amount to poo poo questions we have. Pretty sure the AIs will complain about the quality of the questions more than us (throwing wrong judgement on question regulations).

Comment: @Alviandoh yes, I worry about that too.  What if the AI achieved sentience?  Exposed only to SO questions, it would surely become genocidal and attempt to exterminate the human race:(

Comment: @MartinJames Don't worry, after being exposed to SO questions, just downvote those AIs and they will disappear eventually

Comment: Genocidal? Pish-tosh. Merely more sarcastic.

Comment: I know I'm late, but one time my teacher decided to grade an essay of mine with AI and the teacher gave me an A and the AI gave me an F. And the AI was fully trained as well. So There;'s that, Maching Learning sucks.

Comment: @user4581301 'Merely more sarcastic'... of course - I am English.  Sarcasm is a condition for UK citizenship:)