# Can I ask whether a particular tutorial has errors?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I need to know if the following question can be posted on Stack Overflow, or if it's not appropriate here.

> I was following the official Android tutorial, when I got a problem [Missing button while executing first official Android tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367788/missing-button-while-executing-first-official-android-tutorial) various users told me that the problem was originated by fragment file, so they gave me some URL to fragment file tutorials. By the way these tutorials, in official Android tutorials website come (chronologically) after the tutorial I was following (number one). In Stack Overflow comments I supposed the tutorial was buggy because the code supplied was not working, and the missing code parts are avaible only in next tutorials. What do you think about?

My question is essentially "is this tutorial buggy?"

Comment: @Mat yes it is what I want to ask. What StackExchange website can I ask in?

Comment: I have a feeling the tutorial works fine, and it's something on the eclipse project template that isn't right. I followed that tutorial (I think) without issues a while back.

Comment: I just checked your post and the doc. The tutorial is fine.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A question like the following isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow:

> Is [this tutorial] buggy?

Knowing whether the tutorial actually has a bug isn't what you're actually after, presumably. What you're after is getting the thing to work.

In order to get help getting the thing to work, you should ask a detailed question about exactly what isn't working, including what your problematic code/setup looks like and what errors/misbehavior you're encountering. Do add a reference to the tutorial section where you're stuck for additional information.

Once you've done that, people will hopefully point out what's wrong in your code, configuration or anything else. And your problem will then be solved.

This isn't limited to tutorials either. If you're fighting with something that looks like a bug in a library or framework, do the same thing. Produce a minimal piece of code that exhibits the issue, describe what you think should happen and what does happen.

(I'd advise you *not* to mention you think it's a bug in the library/compiler/whatever - it very often isn't and you'll generally get a better reception if you phrase your question as "What am I doing wrong/how can I fix this?" than "Is this a bug in [foo]?".)

---

As a side effect you'll know whether the tutorial/library/whatever indeed has a bug or if you skipped/misinterpreted/misused parts of it. No need for a second question.

If it turns out there really *is* a bug in there, then please think about filing a bug or somehow reporting the issue to the tutorial's/library's authors. Until the issue is fixed, people that encounter it will probably find your Stack Overflow question and (hopefully) find a solution/workaround there - which is what they need too.

Comment: +1: it seems [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring?cb=1) is taking some effect ;)