# Are questions concerning issues with a tutorial considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

Almost two months ago I have answered a question related to a very specific tutorial where OP had some questions about it. While this tutorial exposes a good example it lacks a fundamental explanation about how every part works.

To be honest the title of the question <strike>is not</strike> wasn't the best and probably someone might have been tempted to flag the question as off-topic: <strike>JXLoginPane tutorial?</strike> <strike>Doubts related to JXLoginPane example</strike> [Problems understanding the framework around a JXLoginPane example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046336/jxloginpane-tutorial). That's probably what I would have done if I knew nothing of the subject.  However (and fortunately I guess) it wasn't flagged and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25047554/1795530) was well received.

The thing is there are no good tutorial out there about this topic and I think Stack Overflow could be helpful in this sense. I mean **not by writing an entire** tutorial because that's not SO's purpose. I mean **by making an exception** with this kind of questions in this particular scenario and leaving them on-topic.

A matter of fact if I type "JXLoginPane tutorial" on Google the first result is the aforementioned question/answer:

[image]

So, could this kind of questions be considered on-topic?

---

PS: I have read this related question but it's not exactly the same case as OP wasn't asking about some bug but for clarification:

- [Can I ask whether a particular tutorial has errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269615/can-i-ask-whether-a-particular-tutorial-has-errors)

Comment: You might want to consider the approach taken by the [tag:scala] tag wiki.

Comment: *"To be honest the title of the question is not the best and probably someone might have been tempted to flag the question as off-topic"* ... so, if it's not really asking for a tutorial, and your answer isn't really a tutorial, and the question isn't closed (yet) ... why didn't you edit the title?

Answer (score 12):

It's not a question of whether it's on topic, it's a question of scope.  Writing an entire tutorial on a topic is generally going to be "Too Broad" for an SO question.

If you want to write a tutorial on a topic that's great, SO probably just isn't the correct place to host that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25047554/1795530) look like an *entire* tutorial to you?

Comment: @dic19 It sounded like you were asking if it's okay to write one.  If you're not asking if it's okay to write a tutorial then what *are* you asking?

Comment: Yes I realize that... My bad :( I've edited my question. Anyway I think nobody understood what I meant so I will probably have to make a better question.

Comment: There are borderline cases though, where the question is thoroughly self-answered and intended as a canonical duplicate-target.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's why I said "generally" and not "always".  They *can* be written in such a way as to limit the scope enough to be an acceptable SO question, but doing so is quite hard, and in most cases the questions end up being too broad.